# PHP removing value within forEach loop from mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, foreach

I am running the following queries on my SQL databases. What I want to do next is to remove all the users from `$result_users` whose `user_ID` is also a `receiverID` in the `$result_sender` array. To do so I have created the following code, however I am not sure if my approach is correct. I have found online that what should be done is `unset($array[$key])`, however all the examples I found were normal arrays, and not obtained from SQL databases, hence I'm not sure how to proceed in this situation

```
 $retrieve_potential_matches_sender = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT senderID, receiverID FROM match_instance WHERE senderID = '$sender'");
 $retrieve_all_users = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT user_id, sex, latitude, longitude FROM users_with_fb");
 $result_sender = mysqli_fetch_array($retrieve_potential_matches_sender);
 $result_users = mysqli_fetch_array($retrieve_all_users);

 if count($result_sender) > 0 { 

 foreach ($result_sender as $sendingID) {

   foreach ($result_users as $userValue) { 

     if ($userValue["user_id"] == $sendingID["receiverID"] {

       unset($userValue);
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Why dont you just do a join in sql?

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_array  the function returns a SINGLE row of results from the query, not all of the results. you're not looping on all the rows, you're looping on the fields of a SINGLE row. and you really need to learn about sql joins. running two queries in parallel like that is highly inefficient (even you were doing it correctly).

Comment: @Reto would it be something like `SELECT users_with_fb.user_id, users_with_fb.sex, users_with_fb.latitude, users_with_fb.longitude
FROM users_with_fb
INNER JOIN match_instance 
ON users_with_fb.user_id !=match_instance.receiverID;` ?

Comment: Yes or you could use a sub query like this: `SELECT user_id, sex, latitude, longitude FROM users_with_fb WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT receiverID FROM match_instance); `

Comment: If I wanted it to not be equal to either the receiverID or the senderID would it be : `SELECT users_with_fb.user_id, users_with_fb.sex, users_with_fb.latitude, users_with_fb.longitude FROM users_with_fb WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT receiverID FROM match_instance) AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT senderID FROM match_instance);` ?

Comment: In this case you should better do: `SELECT user_id, sex, latitude, longitude FROM users_with_fb WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT receiverID, senderID FROM match_instance);`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a sub query like this:

`SELECT user_id, sex, latitude, longitude FROM users_with_fb WHERE user_id NOT IN (SELECT receiverID FROM match_instance);`

Answer (score 0):

You are unsetting the variable used by the loop, not the value in the actual array. This should be what you are looking for:

```
foreach ($result_sender as $sendingID) {

  foreach ($result_users as $key => $userValue) { 

     if ($userValue["user_id"] == $sendingID["receiverID"] {

       unset($result_users[$key]);
     }
  }
}
```